# Swift 4 UIWebView/WKWebView HTTPS Proxy

Tags: ios, proxy, uiwebview, swift4, wkwebview

I've read a lot of topics and questions but still unsure. When making an app in Swift 4 for newest iOS there is no alternative to HTTPS proxy other than using NetworkExtension and VPN tunneling?

On UIWebView there's only HTTP Proxy left and as far as I know, WKWebView doesn't have any possibility to proxy other than using NetworkExtension.

Any ideas or advices?

Comment: did you figure how to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately no.